# Is it possible to use zen coding indexes within a parent element to apply to a child?

Tags: html, css, emmet

Say you have the zen snippet:

```
div#container>(div.panel>h2{this is the header inside panel $})*3
```

it will evaluate to:

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="panel">
        <h2>this is the header inside panel 1</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="panel">
        <h2>this is the header inside panel 1</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="panel">
        <h2>this is the header inside panel 1</h2>
    </div>
</div>
```

Is there a way to make it evaluate passing the index of the multiplied element though to its children?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It’s a bug of current version of Zen Coding core: it’s incorrectly set-up counter value when group is repeated. But in this particular case you can get desired result with this abbreviation:

```
div#container>div.panel*3>h2{this is the header inside panel $}
```

In the upcoming v0.8 release this bug was fixed, you can test it out here: http://media.chikuyonok.ru/codemirror2/